# _dirname is not defined? app.use(express.static(path.join(_dirname, 'public')));

Tags: javascript

How do I make this heart appear in my console? I have an .env file with PORT=3001 written in it. And I removed bodyParser because it was deprecated and apparently it is built into express now.

The error I'm getting is that _dirname is not defined

```
// Require
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');
// App
const app = express();
// Middlewares
// Morgan
app.use(morgan('dev'));
// View engine ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//Public static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(_dirname, 'public')));
// Body Parser (replaced with express)
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    entended: false
}));                     
app.use(express.json()); 
// Helmet
app.use(helmet());
// External routes




// Listener
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server beating  on PORT (PORT)');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's double `_`. So replace `_dirname` with `__dirname`:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `__dirname` instead of `_dirname`

More information about https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname